# Edges in image are not smooth after setpixels in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am using getpixels() and setpixels() api. From Bitmap using getpixel api getting one by one pixel and doing some modification and setting the pixel, doing this operation for all pixels in a loop. I could see same alpha value for all pixels not able to find the reason.
Please suggest a solution.
[image: Please find the attached image to see the issue]

```
                   int width, height;
           height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
           width = bmpOriginal.getWidth(); 

            int[] pix = new int[width * height];
            bmpOriginal.getPixels(pix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);



            int R, G, B, A; 


            float[] hsv = new float[3];
            float[] hsv2 = new float[3];
            float[] hsv3 = new float[3];



            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int index = y * width + x;
                R = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;     //bitwise shifting
                G = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                B = pix[index] & 0xff;            


                Color.RGBToHSV(R, G, B, hsv);                   

                int value = tempBitmap.getPixel(x, y);


               Color.colorToHSV(value, hsv2);                           

                int x = Color.HSVToColor(hsv3);
                pix[index] = x;


                }

            }  

            bmpOriginal.setPixels(pix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: how did you solved this problem? I am also stuck on this.

Comment: Me too stuck on this.

Comment: @Vikrant_Dev have you got ans. still looking for solution

Comment: @dasdasd do you have any idea? please help

Answer (score 2):

Use `setAntiAlias(true)` api on your paint object to turn on anti aliasing.
Also try `setFilterBitmap(true)` on paint.

Make a `BitmapDrawable` out of your bitmap. Then, call `mBmpdrawable.setAntiAlias(true);` before using it. Also try calling `mBmpdrawable.setFilterBitmap(true)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this now but still I could see this problem. Kindly explain bit more on this.

Comment: I am not using paint object after getting the pixel and before setting the pixel.Using color api I am changing the color. So In this case how to  apply setAntiAlis() ?

Comment: make a bitmapdawable and set antialias on it.. check updated answer

Comment: I have tried this but no change. After setting the pixels I have created BitmapDrawable from bitmap.        bmpOriginal.setPixels(pix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
          
          Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmpOriginal);
          ((BitmapDrawable) d).setAntiAlias(true);
          ((BitmapDrawable) d).setFilterBitmap(true);
          
          bmpOriginal = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();